# Concatenate 2 numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm in need of a function to concatenate 2 numbers in SQL Server

eg

```
getuserid(3,333) = 3333
getuserid(8,5) = 8005
getuserid(2,11) = 2011
```

It should return the result based on the length of second parameter (like 3rd example)

I tried converting it to string and using case statements I concatenated it. But, I feel that,this can be done mathematically in a more effective manner. Can anyone please suggest a way.?

By the by, the output returned should be a numeric type.!

Comment: CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(2))+CAST(field2 AS VARCHAR(2))

Comment: Is the length of the output at least four digits? How do you know how many zeroes you need to pad with?

Comment: @Alexander K : first parameter is a single digit. Second parameter will be maximum 3 digit number

Comment: If this concatenation is simple as you describe possible you can use `getuserid(x, y) = x * 1000 + y `

Comment: @AlexanderK : It would be 15555

Comment: Since you already have a working solution, it would help to show your existing code and explain why it isn't good enough for you and also what "more effective" means to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.concat_num (@a INT, @b INT)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

  RETURN CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @a) + REPLICATE('0', CASE WHEN LEN(@b) > 2 THEN LEN(@b) ELSE 3 END - LEN(@b)) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @b))

END
```

Output:

```
-----------
3333
-----------
8005
-----------
2011
-----------
15555
```

Comment: Please note my last statement.! Also I have done this. I need to doing something mathematically..

Answer (score 8):

Looks like this will do it:

```
select num1 * 1000 + num2
```

Why do you need a function for this simple math?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your question

....*It should return the result based on the length of second parameter*.....

That means probably you meant

```
getuserid(3,333) = 3333
getuserid(8,5) = 85
getuserid(2,11) = 211
```

I have used `LEN()` on second parameter and `Power()` function on 10

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.concat_num (@a INT, @b INT)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN

  RETURN  @a * POWER(10,LEN(@b)) + @b

END
```

Answer (score 1):

I have little modified above solution provided by @Devrat, because I want to just concatenate values rather adding 000 between, and if the second number is 0 it will return only first number

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.concat_num (@a INT, @b INT)
RETURNS INT
AS BEGIN
  IF @b = 0 
   BEGIN
 RETURN @a
   END  
  ELSE
   BEGIN
 RETURN CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @a) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), @b))
   END
  RETURN 0

END
```